# Why can't I add objects to my NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, object, nsmutablearray

For some reason since last night Xcode just stopped working properly, it doesn't autocorrect, provide code hints, and doesn't recognize errors until built. And now I can't even get my code to work 100% properly.

My objects won't add to my array.

.h

```
  NSMutableArray *notesTitle;
  NSMutableArray *notesBody;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    notesTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    notesBody = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

...
 [notesTitle addObject:noteTitle.text];
 [notesBody addObject:noteText.text];

///noteTitle.text and noteText.text do contain Text
```

And Both Array's turn out as null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For some reason since last night Xcode just stopped working properly,
>   it doesn't autocorrect, provide code hints, and doesn't recognize
>   errors until built. And now I can't even get my code to work 100%
>   properly.

Unrelated;  try removing your derived data directory entirely and rebuilding.

> And Both Array's turn out as null

Are you sure your `viewDidLoad` method has been invoked?  Set a breakpoint (or print something out).